# change mount points to another directory

Tags: home-directory, symbolic-link, mountpoint

I want to change the directory's of four mount points to /home folder in hopes of moving programs to another directory.

I am in need to move `/tmp /usr /opt` and `/var` to the `/home`directory like

```
/home/tmp
/home/usr
/home/opt
/home/var
```

I am wondering if i could set this up during installation, if this setup is possible. And will the "bind" be kept during a shutdown and restart. As the home mount point will be setup to a different drive.

(I heard that `ftab` is one command to use, but I don't really want to try that because I do not know how to really work the `ftab` command. Nor do i want to use it and mess up my system)

**EDIT:** `/usr` will be excluded.

Comment: There is no such thing as "man in".  There is the `man` command, which prints the manual for a command, and there is the `ln` command ( not `in` ) which creates hard and symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

As @psusi rightly stated in his comment "There is no such thing as `man in`. There is the `man` command, which prints the manual for a command, and there is the `ln` command ( not `in` ) which creates hard and symbolic links."

'ln' doesn't actually move anything. For more information issue the command `man ln` or see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ln.1.html

Comment: I am making corrections to my questions, my bad.

Comment: @weezle1234 If I had to guess (which clearly I do) you have space on your home partition and are running short elsewhere and have decided that `ln` is the way to go. Providing more information about your current setup and your desired end result will likely result in better answers. Check the Related column to the right of this question for numerous related questions which may already have your answer,

Comment: @weezle1234 drop me a comment when you've clarified your question and I'll revisit it and revise my answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This not a good to move this folder to your `/home` directory.
However, you make seemlink to them using `ln -s` ([usage](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora16/man1/ln.1.html))